# How do I fix a Cross language installation problem in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a SQL Server 2008 setup and I've been given a Cross Language Installation failure.  More specifically:

Rule "cross language installation: failed.
the Setup language is different than the language of existing SQL Server features.  To continue, use SQL Server Setup installation media of the same language as the installed SQL Server features.

I do not have SQL Server Express installed and I browsed through "Add or Remove Programs" and was unable to find anything that looked like it was a previous version of SQL.

Any tips?

Comment: what version of SQL are you installing and what version of Windows? english? Both? Windows XP? Vista? 2003 Server?

Comment: SQL 2008, windows XP Pro SP3, English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have uninstalled all of your old SQL Server versions.  Also you *must* restart the installer if you have not done that when you began installation.

Answer (score 12):

I restarted the setup after facing the same problem, and I realized that man should not close the installation center till the setup process is completed. If you leave it open it will work.

Comment: Glad to hear Fred. Crazy software, is not it? :)
A similar was, when I tried to install DB2 on my Windows. The installer did not want to start. It turned out, that the problem is, that my local in windows was hungarian, and the installer was web page based, and the pages were not shipped with HU local. I copied the english local with HU folder, and it worked. It was a similar pain to realize :)

Comment: Wow. It's really picky! It took me about two hours to install visual studio, SQL server and github last night. Talk about a lot of work!

Answer (score 2):

All I had to do was exit the installer and start the process again.  For some reason it worked the second time around.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today when installing SQL Server 2008 Express on a computer that has never had an instance of SQL Server installed.

I found that "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward compatibility" was installed.  I removed this via Add/Remove Programs and was able to successfully install SQL Server 2008 Express afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Current Windows Language interface for the needed language you want to install. 
That will make it possible for the Installer to launch the Localized version.

Answer (score 0):

If you've previously installed SQL on the machine (or apparently some RedGate tools) have you checked for any SQL detritus in the registry?

If not then the [MS forums](https://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3493955&SiteID=1) have details of some reg keys to look out for, and some of the links are worth following for advice on what to delete from the registry.

Answer (score 0):

On my installation of Sql Server 2008 Express, this was caused by having Sql Server 2005 Express Tools installed while trying to install 2008.  Uninstalling 2005 Tools fixed the problem.  I was able to keep Sql Server 2005 Express, including Sql Server 2005 Backward compatability; only had to nuke tools.